# SOLR and PHP help needed

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, solr

I have understood how to add xml files to SOLR and be able to search them via the SOLR ADMIN interface...

I need to know however, how to make SOLR work with PHP, and index MYSQL records...

**This is what I want to do:**
I have a mysql `table`, which I would like to add to `SOLR` (index it), so that instead of searching the MYSQL table directly via `PHP`, I first take the `querystring`, send it to SOLR, and then SOLR sends back results in form of `ID:nrs`, then use the ID:s to query mysql and fetch proper records...

I have no clue on how to communicate with SOLR using PHP, any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good article here that will help you through the integration of PHP and SOLR:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-apachesolr/

There's a number of PHP interfaces to SOLR, that article references PHP SOLR client:

http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/

but there's also this:

http://pecl.php.net/package/solr

Comment: Is there any way I can add my XML file directly using php code for indexing to SOLR ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you start with using DataImportHandler (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) for indexing the database and use one of the many Solr PHP clients (see [SolrPHP wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP)). Note that Solr also emits JSON responses so if you are familiar with JSON, it may be the easiest way to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I've been there too and it was the first time I found the Internet to be annoying! Maybe that was because I was in such a hurry to learn it in under a minute. Here's what i suggest:

- 1.
  Don't panic. Understanding the working or even just the implementation takes more than just a few seconds. So, keep some time aside for this.
- 2.
  Learn how to use JSON. You can use this to communicate across languages.
- 3.
  Check the [apache site](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPHP)